# Automatic navigation to next page fails in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have a page X in a Windows Store App (Windows 8.1) that gets shown after the splash screen. I want to evaluate something while / after the page loads, before the user can interact with the page.

Depending on the evaluation I want to do one of the two:

1. Just show the page X to the user and only navigate to page Y when the user clicks a button
2. Skip the current page and navigate to page Y automatically

1 works fine.

2 doesn't. I tried with calling this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Y)) in the constructor, which didn't work because this.Frame was still null. Then I tried calling it in LoadState and OnNavigatedTo, but while in both cases this.Frame is not null, the Navigate() method returns false, which means the navigation fails. I tried to step into the method in Debugging, but it didn't work (?).

One hint is, that when hitting a breakpoint in the Navigate() code line when it gets called automatically, the screen still shows the splash screen, so it seems the UI elements have not been loaded yet. So the final question is: **How can I do the evaulation and automatic navigation with all elements being loaded (or just so that it works)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why you would call `Frame.Navigate(...)` in `OnNavigatedFrom`, but I can suggest two options that work for me:

1. Navigate to the second page in `OnNavigatedTo`: Although this doesn't work out of the box, it does when instructing the dispatcher to do the navigation:

   ```
   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
   {
       public MainPage()
       {
           this.InitializeComponent();
       }

       protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
       {
           base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

           this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
           {
               this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
           });
       }
   }
   ```
2. An even easier solution is to do the navigation within the first page's `Loaded` event:

   ```
   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
   {
       public MainPage()
       {
           this.InitializeComponent();

           this.Loaded += (sender, args) =>
           {
               this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
           };
       }
   }
   ```

Of course, in both cases you can add whatever calculation you like within the lambda expression before calling `Frame.Navigate(...)`

EDIT: As a third alternative, maybe you should think about moving the calculation and decision part to `OnLaunched` in App.xaml.cs, and load either the first or the second page as root page, instead of opening the first page and immediately navigating on to the second?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for. Solution 1 works perfectly. Few things: 1) I meant OnNavigatedTo instead of ~From, edited that in my question. 2) I might try adding a handler to the loaded event later. Actually that's the event I was looking for. How could I have known about it? I thought I'd have to override them like OnNavigatedTo etc. 3) Thx for the suggestion, but I'd like to show a progress bar and more during the calculation and also maybe use the code for other pages, nut just at app startup. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry I was a bit too quick. The navigation now works (with both method 1 and 2). But no UI elements of the page get shown (in neither of the two methods). So the Loaded event seems to get fired before the UI elements of the page are loaded? How can I load and actually show the page, show a progress bar and automatically navigate to the next page after some calculations?

Comment: You are right, it just shows the splash screen instead of the first page while calculating. However, you should be able to combine the two approaches and use the `Dispatcher.RunAsync(...)` version within the Loaded event. Just tested it, and it shows the loading screen (or whatever is present on the first page) and then switches to the second page.

Comment: I had that, but I was using "Task.Delay(2000).Wait()" as fake calculation instead of "await Task.Delay(2000)". With await everything works fine (as intended for not blocking the UI with Wait()). Even your mentioned first approach works (not using the Loaded Event, but navigating in OnNavigatedTo() and also navigationHelper_LoadState().